# LinkedIn API JavaScript SDK integration in angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, linkedin-api

I would like to implement access to the LinkedIn API as an Angular 2 service using their Javascript SDK. But to load it successfully I need to get it using a html script tag with configuration information inside. Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [API_KEY]
    onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
    authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```

[Reference](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk)

This requires me to manipulate the DOM in my Angular2 service, and I am pretty sure that's not the right way to go about this. What would be the right way to load the LinkedIn JS SDK in an Angular2 application?